# Android Studio Giraffe IDE internal error, java.lang.ClassCastException, everytime I launch Studio

Tags: android-studio, classcastexception, android-studio-girafee

```
Android Studio Giraffe | 2022.3.1 Patch 2
Build #AI-223.8836.35.2231.10811636, built on September 15, 2023
```

Runtime version: 17.0.6+0-17.0.6b829.9-10027231 aarch64
VM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o.
macOS 13.4.1

GC: G1 Young Generation, G1 Old Generation
Memory: 2048M
Cores: 8
Metal Rendering is ON

---

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: class com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.PsiErrorElementImpl cannot be cast to class org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElement (com.intellij.psi.impl.source.tree.PsiErrorElementImpl is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.util.lang.PathClassLoader @f5f2bb7; org.jetbrains.kotlin.psi.KtElement is in unnamed module of loader com.intellij.ide.plugins.cl.PluginClassLoader @2fd6fb23)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.deployment.liveedit.PsiListener.handleChangeEvent(PsiListener.kt:119)
    at com.android.tools.idea.run.deployment.liveedit.PsiListener.beforeChildReplacement(PsiListener.kt:59)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl.notifyPsiTreeChangeListener(PsiManagerImpl.java:376)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl.fireEvent(PsiManagerImpl.java:351)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiManagerImpl.beforeChildReplacement(PsiManagerImpl.java:224)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DiffLog$ReplaceEntry.doActualPsiChange(DiffLog.java:102)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DiffLog.performActualPsiChange(DiffLog.java:45)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DiffLog$1.runInner(DiffLog.java:247)
    at com.intellij.pom.impl.PomTransactionBase.run(PomTransactionBase.java:27)
    at com.intellij.pom.core.impl.PomModelImpl.lambda$runTransaction$1(PomModelImpl.java:111)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DebugUtil.performPsiModification(DebugUtil.java:481)
    at com.intellij.pom.core.impl.PomModelImpl.lambda$runTransaction$2(PomModelImpl.java:104)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$executeNonCancelableSection$3(CoreProgressManager.java:222)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:628)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$computeInNonCancelableSection$4(CoreProgressManager.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Cancellation.computeInNonCancelableSection(Cancellation.java:95)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeInNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.executeNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:221)
    at com.intellij.pom.core.impl.PomModelImpl.runTransaction(PomModelImpl.java:93)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DiffLog.lambda$doActualPsiChange$0(DiffLog.java:244)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeStyleManagerImpl.lambda$performActionWithFormatterDisabled$4(CodeStyleManagerImpl.java:451)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.PostprocessReformattingAspect.disablePostprocessFormattingInside(PostprocessReformattingAspect.java:130)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeStyleManagerImpl.performActionWithFormatterDisabled(CodeStyleManagerImpl.java:479)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.source.codeStyle.CodeStyleManagerImpl.performActionWithFormatterDisabled(CodeStyleManagerImpl.java:450)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DiffLog.doActualPsiChange(DiffLog.java:232)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.lambda$doCommit$5(DocumentCommitThread.java:306)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.commitToExistingPsi(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:422)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.lambda$finishCommitInWriteAction$5(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:396)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.registerIndicatorAndRun(CoreProgressManager.java:679)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeUnderProgress(CoreProgressManager.java:635)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.lambda$computeInNonCancelableSection$4(CoreProgressManager.java:230)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.Cancellation.computeInNonCancelableSection(Cancellation.java:99)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computeInNonCancelableSection(CoreProgressManager.java:230)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.lambda$finishCommitInWriteAction$6(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:391)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.executeInsideCommit(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:507)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.finishCommitInWriteAction(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:389)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerImpl.finishCommitInWriteAction(PsiDocumentManagerImpl.java:136)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase$2.run(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:356)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runWriteAction(ApplicationImpl.java:980)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.PsiDocumentManagerBase.finishCommit(PsiDocumentManagerBase.java:353)
    at com.intellij.psi.impl.DocumentCommitThread.lambda$commitUnderProgress$2(DocumentCommitThread.java:141)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.NonBlockingReadActionImpl$Submission.lambda$safeTransferToEdt$6(NonBlockingReadActionImpl.java:633)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.runWithWritingAllowed(TransactionGuardImpl.java:209)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.access$100(TransactionGuardImpl.java:21)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl$1.run(TransactionGuardImpl.java:191)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl$3.run(ApplicationImpl.java:454)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.doRun(FlushQueue.java:74)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.runNextEvent(FlushQueue.java:114)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.FlushQueue.flushNow(FlushQueue.java:36)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.security.ProtectionDomain$JavaSecurityAccessImpl.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.defaultDispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:909)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue._dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:756)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$5(IdeEventQueue.java:437)
    at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.CoreProgressManager.computePrioritized(CoreProgressManager.java:787)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$6(IdeEventQueue.java:436)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.TransactionGuardImpl.performActivity(TransactionGuardImpl.java:105)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.performActivity(IdeEventQueue.java:615)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.lambda$dispatchEvent$7(IdeEventQueue.java:434)
    at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runIntendedWriteActionOnCurrentThread(ApplicationImpl.java:838)
    at com.intellij.ide.IdeEventQueue.dispatchEvent(IdeEventQueue.java:480)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.desktop/java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

---

I am reporting this issue via IDE from many weeks. But no resolution. Kindly let me know if there is any fix for this.

I have noticed this issue after enabling

```
kotlin { 
    explicitApi = ExplicitApiMode.Strict 
}
```

only for my library module. It's not enabled for app module.

Comment: Can you provide the build.gradle of the project?

Comment: Yes. If you are asking for project level build.gragle, it has only plugins listed below
`plugins {
    id 'com.android.application' version '8.1.2' apply false
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android' version '1.9.0' apply false
    id 'com.android.library' version '8.1.2' apply false
}`

Comment: Also, I have noticed this issue after enabling `kotlin { explicitApi = ExplicitApiMode.Strict }` only for my library module. It's not enabled for app module.